# Busboy throwing undefined exception

Tags: node.js

I am getting the following exception when I invoke the /list method using the following command

```
'curl -v  http://ec2-54-68-202-47.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/list/?name=test'
```

**Error :**

> 110.175.53.235 - - [Sun, 05 Oct 2014 13:08:27 GMT] "GET /list/?name=dafsdf HTTP/1.1" 500 1273 "-" "curl/7.26.0" TypeError:
>   Cannot call method 'on' of undefined

Its fine if I invoke the '/image/upload' url.

```
// Import required modules
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');



var app = express();

app.use(busboy());
app.use(morgan('combined'));

app.get('/list', function(req, res) {
        console.log("Hit the url /list");
        req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val) {
                //console.log('Field [' +fieldname);               
                res.send("data received");
        });
        //req.pipe(req.busboy);
});

app.post('/image/upload', function(req, res) {
        req.busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename) {
                ...
                res.send("file received");
        });
        req.pipe(req.busboy);
});

// Run the application on port 3000
app.listen(8080, function() {
        console.log('Echo Application running at %d', 8080);
});
```

Comment: You sure you can use busboy with a GET request?

Comment: Using a body parser for GET/HEAD/similar requests is useless because those types of requests shouldn't have bodies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Busboy is used to parse Incoming form data, so it's meant for POST requests.

In GETting a list, you'd be better off using the regular syntax ie: req.params

In the words of [mscdex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2050455/mscdex)

> busboy works for any request, however connect-busboy specifically does
>   not set up req.busboy for GET, HEAD, other requests that don't
>   typically contain a body, or the Content-Type is not
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data

Comment: `busboy` works for any request, however `connect-busboy` specifically [does not set up `req.busboy`](https://github.com/mscdex/connect-busboy/blob/b9175fc77ddcca15e6db30cd309ecabecae76325/index.js#L9-L14) for `GET`, `HEAD`, other requests that don't typically contain a body, or the `Content-Type` is not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.